# Изменения иконки в VS C#

Tags: c#

Вот скажите, у меня есть Form1 и Form2, Form2 - это админ понель, а и ней можно изменять иконку Form1...но вот как это сделать я не понял...
У меня есть Button1, Button2,TextBox1. Я пытался сделать этот код, но он не работает.

> Form1.Icon = OpenFileDialog1.FileName;

Comment: совет на будущие: называйте элементы управления(да и любые другие переменные) более вразумительно!

Answer (score 1):

> Form1.Icon = System.Drawing.Icon.ExtractAssociatedIcon("путь");

а уж как путь получить, я думаю, вопросов не возникает?

Comment: Спасибо, это уже я сам.